# Disable changing of value in JS Function through Inspect Element By the USER

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, web-inspector

I have a JS function to delete the user's own post.

```
Function delete(post_id)
{
 //Here comes AJAX call to delete.php file

 // In delete.php file i have a query to delete the post from DB using that
    post_id parameter.

}
```

**My Question is:**

1. Through inspect element, the user can change the function **post_id** value, So how can i prevent it from getting changed?
2. If that cannot be blocked means, how can i retain my old value itself, that is whatever the user change, should not get affect the original function **post_id** value.

**For example:**

user posted 2 posts with post_id 1 and 2 respectively.

if the user wants to delete the 2nd post means, he can use 2nd post's delete button to delete that post.

**Function will be Like:**

```
Function delete(2) //post_id is 2
{
 //AJAX call to delete.php
}
```

How to **prevent** user from changing the **post_id** in function to **1** ?

If that cannot be prevented means, how can i prevent from passing this changed **post_id** to **delete.php**

**Delete.php**:

```
"DELETE FROM `posts` WHERE `postid`='$_POST[post_id]' and user_id='$_SESSION[id]'";
```

Comment: Implement a server side logic where `post-id` should be deleted which only belongs to current logged in user! End-user can never access server side code...

Comment: @Rayon, yes i have that one "DELETE FROM `posts` WHERE `id`='$_POST[post_id]' and user_id='$_SESSION[id]'";

Comment: Then do not worry about what end user could do..

Comment: My problem is, if they change the **post_id** which is belongs to them means, that post will get deleted right ?. That is what my query is.

Comment: what harm will that make ?

Comment: @Rayon, I don't want them to delete some other unrelated post, which was posted some years ago instead of this.

Comment: @Rayon There is no harm in it, but as a developer or provider, we need to prevent them to doing it right?

Answer (score 1):

In your `delete.php`, you can put a `SESSION` check if this user has the right to access that data before proceeding with the delete.

Even if the user changes the `id`, as long as this `id` is assigned to him/her, he/she has the rights to delete that row on your database.

It will still be on him/her alone the fault for removing a row in your database.

---

If you still want to retain the deleted post, you can add another column for your table, let's say `status`. It will only have two types of value, `1` or `0`. The value `1` means that it is active and viewable, and if it is `0`, means it is hidden (*the user will actually think that the removed post is deleted permanently*).

When the user decides to delete his/her own post, you will just run an `UPDATE` query and make that row to `0`. It will still be in your database, but is hidden to him/her and all other users of your system. You can create an administrator page where you can filter deleted (hidden) and active post.

Even if a user changes the `GET` parameter in the URL, as long as you have a condition of `WHERE status = 0`, it will not be view-able in his/her end.

---

Or you can restrict a user from deleting his/her own old post. By putting a range in your `DELETE` query (*assuming that your table has a TIMESTAMP or DATETIME column*).

```
... WHERE id = ? AND user_id = ? AND date_posted < ? AND date_posted > ?
```

---

### Note:

There is no way to prevent the users of your system to change the elements in their end. Even if you disable the `right click` using javascript, or having a lot of interactive validation in the front-end, and any procedure-alike, it will still all end in your back-end validation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer friend, but i have this thing already "DELETE FROM `posts` WHERE `id`='$_POST[post_id]' and user_id='$_SESSION[id]'";

Comment: But my concern is they should not even delete there own posts also, by changing the value through function, so please provide some other way.

Comment: If the user should not delete a post that is posted by himself, then don't offer it in the first place. Remove your delete function.

Comment: I said, the user should not delete some other posts which they posted earlier by changing the post_id in function.

Comment: @VigneshChinnaiyan - about your other concern, I have some few other suggestions on my updated answer.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i need to prevent user from changing the parameter of the function. Is there any way to do that so ? Timestamp thing doesn't sounds good.

Comment: @VigneshChinnaiyan - There is no way to prevent the users on changing the value of the elements in their end. What you can do is to verify each sent request from the users.

Comment: Ok, How to check the sent request?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114300/discussion-between-vignesh-chinnaiyan-and-logan-wayne).